# ajax script not running or passing variables to php script

Tags: php, ajax

I have been looking all over the internet and tried many solutions but none seem to work for me.

What it is supposed to do is, when it calls the php script it should read from one database and insert it into a local database

If I run the php directly with hard coded variables, it works perfectly

My Ajax:

```
<script>
var server = "<?php echo $server ?>";
var company = "<?php echo $company ?>";
$.ajax({
     url: 'populate_cust.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: ({'server': server, 'company': company}),
 });  
</script>
```

My PHP:

```
$server = $_POST['server'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
```

Comment: This is a fairly minimal example which looks like it should work. What debugging have you done? any errors in your browser's console? If you look in the browser's network tab can you see the ajax call to populate_cust.php executing? What values are sent in the request body? Are they what you expect? What response do you get from the call? what's the result of running `var_dump($_POST);` in the PHP? These are all really basic debugging tasks for looking at ajax calls which you can do before posting a question. Please edit the question above to include this extra info so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different PHP programs.

1. Generates the HTML with the JS that makes the Ajax call in it
2. Assigns POSTed data to variables

They are different programs. They run at different times. They do not share variables.

You need to:

- Not try to use `<?php echo $server ?>` to set a value for `server` (because `$server` hasn't been set). (Ditto for company).
- Change the second script to output something (e.g. with `echo`)
- Inspect the result of making the request (e.g. with a `done()` hander)